# Vite build fails

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to build my app but somehow it fails and I can't find a solution. This is the first time, I'm trying to build and deploy a Vite app,and Im completly lost now.

I've got this error on my console:

```
> vue_weather@0.0.0 build
> vite build

vite v4.2.0 building for production...
✓ 1 modules transformed.
✓ built in 51ms
[vite:build-import-analysis] Parse error @:7:20
file: D:/w/src/App.vue:7:19
5:       <Transition name="page" mode="out-in">
6:         <component :is="Component" />
7:       </Transition>
                      ^
8:     </RouterView>
9:   </div>
error during build:
Error: Parse error @:7:20
    at parse$e (file:///D:/w/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c167897e.js:16018:355)        
    at Object.transform (file:///D:/w/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-c167897e.js:45406:27)
```

The `App.vue` looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen font-Roboto bg-weather-primary">
    <SiteNavigation />
    <RouterView v-slot="{ Component }">
      <Transition name="page" mode="out-in">
        <component :is="Component" />
      </Transition>
    </RouterView>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { RouterView } from "vue-router";
import SiteNavigation from "./components/SiteNavigation.vue";
</script>
```

And here is the `package.json`

```
   {
      "name": "vue_weather",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.3.4",
        "tailwind-scrollbar": "^3.0.0",
        "uid": "^2.0.1",
        "vue": "^3.2.47",
        "vue-router": "^4.1.6"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "postcss": "^8.4.21",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7",
        "vite": "^4.1.4"
      }
    }
```

And lastly the `vite.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path')
const { defineConfig } = require('vite')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.js'),
      name: 'MyLib',
      fileName: (format) => `my-lib.${format}.js`
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

What will be the solution for this issue? I've treid to modify the vite.config.js but I got error still.

Comment: You might have forgotten to import the `Transition` component from the Vue3 Transition API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix parse error during Vue app deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73772926/how-to-fix-parse-error-during-vue-app-deployment)

Comment: adding the `vue()` plugin to vite config will likely fix the error. @yoduh: although the linked question has a couple of answers indicating a solution which will likely work here, it can't have duplicates since it doesn't have an accepted answer.